# Is is possible to return "continue;" in a for loop within another public method?

Tags: php

I'm trying to concise my long methods. I have an `if` inside a `forearch` and I'd like to replace it with a method, similar to:

```
/**
 *
 * @return skips majority of equities to reduce computations and tests limited equities
 */
public static function onlyTestLimitedEquities($equity_symbol)
{
    if ($_SERVER['LOGNAME'] === ConstEQ::LOCALHOST) {
        if (HelperEQ::getOurSymbols($equity_symbol) == 0) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The `if` statement works fine in the foreach:

```
if ($_SERVER['LOGNAME'] === ConstEQ::LOCALHOST) {
    if (HelperEQ::getOurSymbols($equity_symbol) == 0) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

How do I return `continue;` since `EQ::onlyTestLimitedEquities($equity_symbol);`  will not be inside the foreach, or how to create/call this method?

#### Loop

In another method, I have this foreach where `EQ::onlyTestLimitedEquities` can be called:

```
foreach ($large_all_data_object->large_all_symbols_array as $equity_symbol => $equity_symbol_array) {

    EQ::onlyTestLimitedEquities($equity_symbol);

}
```

Comment: Given that your code is already working and in fairly good order, your question might be better suited to our sister site, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You don’t, a `continue` has to literally appear in the loop it controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the `continue` at the place where you have your loop. It cannot be placed in another function.

However, you could change the function to return a boolean, and then in the main code you can execute `continue` on the condition that the function returns `true`:

```
public static function onlyTestLimitedEquities($equity_symbol)
{
    return $_SERVER['LOGNAME'] === ConstEQ::LOCALHOST
        && HelperEQ::getOurSymbols($equity_symbol) == 0;
}
```

... and in the calling code:

```
foreach ($large_all_data_object->large_all_symbols_array as $equity_symbol => $equity_symbol_array) {
    // ...

    if (EQ::onlyTestLimitedEquities($equity_symbol)) continue;

    // ...etc
}
```